# Is there any way to run Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2 in debugging mode with Visual studio 2013?

Tags: debugging, thinktecture-ident-server

I would like to customize the Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2 ,when I was run and open the "http://xxxx.xxxx:17852/InitialConfiguration/Index",it always showed me the "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found".
how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via IIS Express. However, an HTTPS endpoint must be configured as IdentityServer will redirect to an HTTPS URL if it is not running on a secure connection.

1. Open the IdentityServer solution in Visual Studio
2. Select the WebSite project
3. Press <kbd>F4</kbd> to open the Properties panel
4. Change the SSL Enabled property to True

   [image]
5. The SSL URL property is set with an HTTPS URL running on a different port

   [image]
6. Copy the SSL URL value
7. Open the Properties of the project

   [image]
8. On the Web tab, set the Server to IIS Express and the Project URL to the SSL URL value
   [image]
9. Save the project and press <kbd>F5</kbd> to debug
10. On the first run you will get a browser error about the untrusted certificate, click Continue
11. Update the Relying Party application with the SSL URL as the STS endpoint

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would switch to local IIS because it is easier to manage (for me at least). Then create https binding and assign a SSL certificate. You could use [xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) to create CA and SSL certificate or you can reuse IIS Express certificate.

[image: iis bindings]

[image: iis express development certificate]

I know that it is not trusted but for this example it will do. But when you start integrating with some Portal you should have trusted SSL certificate issued to DNS name of the server.

Set IdentityServer to use local IIS

[image: local IIS]

Then run F5. You will see this page:

[image]

Click the red continue and you will get to initial configuration page:

[image]

Comment: thank you pepo, I just followed your reply and solved my problem.